# What happens when I bind to an AliasProperty?

Tags: python, events, kivy

Here's my simplified code:

```
class Player(Widget):
    _health = NumericProperty(100)

    def _get_health(self):
        return self._health

    health = AliasProperty(_get_health, bind=['_health'])
```

I did this to make `health` 'readonly'.

The odd thing is, it doesn't work when I remove `bind=['_health']`.

So my question is: what does `bind=['_health']` actually do? I understand `AliasProperty` allows me to define a getter and optional setter which run when the property is accessed (similar to Python's `@property`).

So what does `bind=['_health']` in this case, and why does the property not work (not reflect the state of underlying `_health`) when I exclude it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bind` argument tells the properties engine which *other* properties to monitor for changes, because they are relevant for the `AliasProperty` under consideration.

Let's take the (simplified) example from the documentation:

```
def get_right(self):
    return self.x + self.width
right = AliasProperty(get_right, bind=['x', 'width'])
```

Here, `right` relies on two other properties. If we only wrote `bind=['x']`, then only changes to `x` would cause a change event to be triggered for `right`, whereas changes to `width` would be ignored (however, if after a change to `width` a change to `x` occurs, an event with the expected value will be fired, and if the value is retrieved manually, it will be correct as well).

Comment: I see. When `right` 'changes', nothing will know about it, unless we explicitly specify we depend on `x` and `width`, in which case an event for the alias property will be raised when they are changed.
Thanks :)